# Magento change shipping price based on products from category x?

Tags: magento

Im looking for a way to change the shipping price if all products in a cart are from a certain category.

Looked into promotions
Where I can make a rule to match all products from category X but cannot change the shipping price, only set it to free shipping.

Comment: have you tried shopping cart rules?

Comment: Yes that only allows me to do based on weight vs destination. Not based on category

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mixed it with catalog rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to roll your own shipping module.

This tutorial has what you need to know to get started:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-shipping-method